# how do i remove the restrictions passcode on my iphone 5c

Tags: iphone

i just bought a used iPhone 5c from someone and it has a restrictions passcode on it from the owner before me and I would like to take it off but dont know the passcode is  there anyway I could take It off .?

Comment: I would hope not as that defeats the object of having a password

Comment: I can have a passcode I just cant reset my phone cus I need the restrictions passcode to do it idk why

Answer (score 0):

Only buy phones that are factory-reset. If you're able to reset it yourself (Settings > Erase All Content and Settings), then it should remove the restrictions

Comment: I tried that and it says I have to put my restrictions passcode in

Comment: @emilyb have you tried through iTunes?

Comment: it keeps saying I have to update my software but I did that already then it says it gunna take 5 hours and I don't have 5 hours